# Reading a 2D array from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, fgets, scanf

I'm attempting to create a program to read a 2D array from a file and then print it out.

The file is set out so that the first line has the number of rows and then the number of columns. After that the array is plotted. An example is as follows:

```
3 5
10.4 15.1 18.5 13.3 20.8
76.5 55.3 94.0 48.5 60.3
2.4 4.6 3.5 4.6 8.9
```

My problem is that i only know how to read the first element of each line using fgets and sscanf so the following numbers are ignored.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

FILE* f = fopen("plottestdata", "r");
char size[20];
int height, width,ii=0,cc,jj,kk;
float array[100][100];
char horiz[500];

if(fgets(size, 20, f)!= NULL){

    sscanf(size,"%d %d", &height, &width);
    printf("%d %d\n",height, width);
}
while(fgets(horiz, 500, f)!=NULL)
{

    if(ii<height)
    {
        for(cc=0;cc<width;cc++)
        {
        sscanf(horiz, "%f", &array[ii][cc]);
        }
    ii++;
    }
}
for(jj=0;jj<width;jj++)
    {
        for(kk=0;kk<height;kk++)
        {
        printf("%f ", array[jj][kk]);
        }
    }
fclose(f);
return 0;
}
```

This gives me an output of the first element of each line repeated multiple times and I understand why but am unsure how to fix it. The file it is reading from is actually a 20x20 array although set out in the same format as the example.

Also, i have left out my error checking for the sake of trying to shortening a long question.

Comment: `sscanf` differs from `fscanf` and `scanf` in that it always starts at the beginning of the string. You can't scan sequentially with subsequent `sscanf` calls. (Well, you can with the `%n` format.) A better approach may be to tokenise the string with `strtok` and then use `strtod` on the tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not resist tweaking and simplifying your code, it was so close, to avoid the use of `fgets` and use `fscanf` to read the values directly. Plus basic error checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MWIDTH  100
#define MHEIGHT 100

int main(void){

    FILE* f;
    int height, width, ii, jj;
    float array[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH];

    if((f = fopen("plottestdata.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        exit(1);

    if(fscanf(f, "%d%d", &height, &width) != 2)
        exit(1);
    if (height < 1 || height > MHEIGHT || width < 1 || width > MWIDTH)
        exit(1);

    for(jj=0; jj<height; jj++)
        for(ii=0; ii<width; ii++)
            if(fscanf(f, "%f", &array[jj][ii]) != 1)
                exit(1);
    fclose(f);

    for(jj=0; jj<height; jj++){
        for(ii=0; ii<width; ii++)
            printf ("%10.1f", array[jj][ii]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
  10.4      15.1      18.5      13.3      20.8
  76.5      55.3      94.0      48.5      60.3
   2.4       4.6       3.5       4.6       8.9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE* f = fopen("plottestdata", "r");
    char size[20];
    int height, width,ii=0,cc,jj,kk;
    char horiz[500];

    if(fgets(size, 500, f)!= NULL){

    sscanf(size,"%d %d", &height, &width);
    printf("%d %d\n",height, width);
    }
    float array[height][width];
    while(fgets(horiz, 500, f)!=NULL)
    {

    if(ii<height)
    {
         sscanf(horiz, "%f %f %f %f %f", &array[ii][0],&array[ii][1],
                    &array[ii][2],
                    &array[ii][3],
                    &array[ii][4]);       
              ii++;
        }
    }
    for(ii=0;ii<height;ii++)
    {
        for(kk=0;kk<width;kk++)
        {
            printf("%.2f ", array[ii][kk]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sscanf(horiz, "%f", &array[ii][cc]); one specifier couldn't store  all the values from horiz,Either you need to split the horiz and write a loop or as you knew that width is 5 then you put 5 specifiers.The above code might help you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading from a file with a hardcoded file name, why not read from `stdin`? You can use `fgets(size, sizeof size, stdin)` to read the first line with the dimensions.

Then use `scanf(" %f", &array[ii][cc)` to read in values one by one.

Be sure to test whether scanf returns 1 and add some error handling if not.

Comment: How would i do this? I haven't used stdin before, im pretty new to programming

Comment: @JackJohnson The `stdin` stream is a `FILE *` stream that is already open for reading when main starts. To supply file data on stdin, you run your program as `program < plottestdata`. Functions like scanf, getchar etc all use stdin.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already found out, you need to scan the next value where you left off after scanning the previous one. Unfortunately, `sscanf` does not have the properties of a stream; it doesn't memorise its last position and always starts afresh if you pass the same string.

Fortunalely, there are many other ways to achieve sequential scanning.

**Tokenisation** You could tokenise your line forst and then parse each token as floating-point number. `strtok` from `string.h>` and `strtod` from `<stdlib.h>` will do that job for you.

```
        char *token = strtok(horiz, " \t\n");

        for (cc = 0; cc < width; cc++) {
            if (token) {                
                array[ii][cc] = strtod(token, NULL);
                token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
            } else {
                array[ii][cc] = 0.0;
            }
        }
```

**Keep track of the tail I** `strtod` has one other characteristic: It tells you exactly where parsing stopped when you supply a pointer to a char pointer. `strtod` also skips leading white space. You can use these two facts to parse floats separated by white space.

```
        char *p = horiz;

        for (cc = 0; cc < width; cc++) {
            char *tail;

            array[ii][cc] = strtod(p, &tail);
            p = tail;
        }
```

**Keep track of the tail II** `sscanf` has a special format that tells you how many characters have been parsed at a certain point in an integer. The above could be written with `sscanf`:

```
       char *p = horiz;

        for (cc = 0; cc < width; cc++) {
            int len;

            sscanf(p, "%f%n", &array[ii][cc], &len);
            p += len;
        }
```

All these work for your example, but none of them does proper error checking. The first example at least makes a half-hearted attempt to catch the case where a line has fewer tokens than the matrix has columns.