# 2D array isn't reading from a .txt document correctly

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I am building a simple program for a University exercise that requires data to be read from a .txt file and fed into a 2D array.

The premise of the program is that the user inputs 10 gene chromosomes (floats) separated by spaces, the program then compares these floats to a .txt file containing a number of gene chromosomes and if it matches one in the .txt file, the user is notified there is a match.

Here is my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

FILE *dnaFile;

int main(){

    //Open the file and assign its address/disk location to file pointer
    dnaFile = fopen("dnaInput.txt", "r"); //Relative pathname used

    //Declaring the Suspect array
    int size = 10;
    float suspect[size];

    //Declaring the Criminal array
    int sizeR = 6;
    int sizeC = 10;
    float criminals[sizeR][sizeC];

    //Read 10 input values into suspect array from keyboard
    printf("\nEnter the 10 chromosomes of the suspect seperated by spaces: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf(" %f", &suspect[i]);

    //Read multiple profiles of 10 values into criminals array from file
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++){
        fscanf(dnaFile, " %f", criminals[i]);

    //Read 10 input values of a criminal into criminals array from the keyboard
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeC; j++)
        fscanf(dnaFile, " %f", &criminals[i][j]);

    }

    //Match user input to the array
    bool match = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeC; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeR; j++)
            if(suspect[i] != criminals[i][j])
                match = false;

    //Display the result

    if (match)
        printf("\nSuccess: A match was found! \n");
    else
        printf("\nFailure: No match was found \n");

}
```

And here is the contents of the .txt file...

```
2.3 3.3 4.5 6.7 7.8 2.1 3.2 4.3 5.2 6.5
2.3 3.3 4.5 6.7 7.8 2.1 3.2 4.3 5.2 6.5
1.3 0.3 9.5 8.7 5.8 4.1 3.2 2.3 6.2 6.9
6.3 9.3 4.3 6.4 7.5 2.9 3.0 4.1 5.3 6.5
6.1 9.4 4.5 6.6 7.4 2.8 3.2 4.4 5.0 6.0
2.3 3.3 4.5 6.6 7.8 2.2 3.2 4.3 5.2 6.5
```

The program complies and executes without issue, though when entering say the first line of contents of the .txt as the input, even though it matches the .txt file, it gives the user a fail output. I've googled arrays to try and find my issue but haven't come across a solution.

Apologies in advance if I have made a rookie mistake, I have only recently started learning C at University.

Comment: "I've googled arrays to try and find my issue but haven't come across a solution." Specifically what things did you try putting into Google, what web pages did you find as a result, and what changes did you try making to the code as a result? What happens when you try using a debugger to trace the execution of the code?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel As I don't know specifically what the issue is, I have tried looking up "feeding into arrays from a text file" to get a direct example, which hasn't helped me find a solution.

Comment: Why would you read a float 15 times, when there appears to be 60 of them. You code incorrectly says 5 rows and you've told us 10 columns. You'd need to read 10*5 times, not 10+5. Both the fscanf loops are dodgy. Think about each of them some more.

Comment: Did you try `c read 2d array from file`? When I do that, I [find](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c+read+2d+array+from+file) multiple fully-worked examples, as well as duplicate Stack Overflow questions, right off the top.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a 2D array from a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998105/reading-a-2d-array-from-a-file-in-c) How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708370/reading-from-txt-file-into-two-dimensional-array-in-c)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nested loops to read into the 2-dimension array:

```
    //Read multiple profiles of 10 values into criminals array from file
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeC; j++) {
            fscanf(dnaFile, " %f", &criminals[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Then when you're searching for the suspect in the array, the outer loop should be by rows, not columns, and you should reset `match` on each row.

Then when comparing `suspect` with `criminals`, you should use `suspect[j]`, not `suspect[i]`, since `j` is the column index.

```
    //Match user input to the array
    bool found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeR; i++) {
        bool match = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeC; j++) {
            if(suspect[j] != criminals[i][j]) {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, though this has partly fixed my issue, it will only read the top entry into the .txt file, any other inputs from the .txt file are met with a fail.

Comment: I can't see any reason for that.

Comment: Testing it is difficult when I'm being returned with "zsh: segmentation fault", do you know what could be causing this? Google tells me it's to do with the program trying to access something the OS "doesn't like" but nothing has suggested how to fix it.

Comment: Use a debugger to see where that';s happening

Comment: First thing I did after googling it was running it through a debugger, all it told me was "exit code 1", and nothing else.

Comment: That's not a segmentation fault. That would come from `exit(1)`, which doesn't appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: I fixed several problems in the matching loops. I've tested the code now, it works for me.